# presto + how to tune the memory.max-data-per-node

Tags: linux, presto

in presto documintation we can see the follwing

[image]

this default configuration about -  `memory.max-data-per-node=128MB` , not considered that presto workers machine can be with different memory size

for example what should be the value of  - `memory.max-data-per-node` in case presto worker is only with `16G RAM`

or

what should be the value of  - `memory.max-data-per-node` in case presto worker is only with `250G RAM` ?

so how to tune the variable - `memory.max-data-per-node` according to machine memory size?